# What does a "3x great-uncle" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I read an essay about family tree and came across this sentence,

> ...has extensively researched the experiences of a 3x great-uncle who fought in the momentous Battle of Waterloo...

What does a "3x great-uncle" mean here? How to express it in a full and formal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, **great-great-great Uncle**. The actual '**3x**' part, would mean '**3 times**'. This refers to the word '**great**', meaning '**great great great**' which would be *3 generations up*. Story may be talking about WWI I assume.

Refer to **this**;

> http://www.rootschat.com/forum/index.php?topic=553686.0

Comment: I know this is not history SE, but I would like to draw your attention to the fact that the famous battle of Waterloo took place in 1815, whereas WWI raged from 1914 to 1918, one hundred years later.

Comment: Not quite common on history, thought WWI was a little early than 1900's. Either way, hope I answered your question. Thanks for the knowledge :-)

Answer (score 4):

It means a great-great-great uncle, which would be a great-great-grandparent's brother or brother-in-law.